# left outer join query in Informix

Tags: informix, outer-join

I have two queries from which I expected to get same result.

First one:

```
select d.serialno, d.location, d.ticket, d.vehicle, o.name, d.parrivaltime, e.etype 
from deliveries d left outer join events e 
on d.serialno=e.eserialno and d.client=e.eclient and d.carrier=e.ecarrier and d.location=e.elocation 
left outer join operators o 
on d.client=o.client AND d.driver=o.code AND d.carrier=o.carrier AND d.location=o.location 
where d.statusmessage='CURRENT' and d.scheduleddate BETWEEN '08/02/2017' AND '08/03/2017' and d.dropno!=0 and d.location in ('MIAMID') AND (e.etype=107 or e.etype=108) 
order by d.location, d.dropno, e.etype;
```

Second one:

```
select d.serialno, d.location, d.ticket, d.vehicle, o.name, d.parrivaltime, e.etype 
from deliveries d, outer events e, outer operators o 
where d.serialno=e.eserialno and d.client=e.eclient and d.carrier=e.ecarrier and d.location=e.elocation 
AND d.client=o.client and d.driver=o.code and d.carrier=o.carrier and d.location=o.location 
AND d.statusmessage='CURRENT' and d.scheduleddate BETWEEN '08/02/2017' AND '08/03/2017' and d.dropno!=0 and d.location in ('MIAMID') AND (e.etype=107 or e.etype=108) 
order by d.location, d.dropno, e.etype;
```

However, from the first query, I got 1044 records. But from the second query, I got 876 records.

I also checked the explain.out file which is as below. But I still cannot figure out why the output record is different.

```
QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 09-06-2017 11:27:22)
------
select d.serialno, d.location, d.ticket, d.vehicle, o.name, d.parrivaltime, e.etype from deliveries d, outer events e, outer operators o where d.serialno=e.eserialno and d.client=e.eclient and d.carrier=e.ecarrier and d.location=e.elocation AND d.client=o.client AND d.driver=o.code AND d.carrier=o.carrier AND d.location=o.location AND d.statusmessage='CURRENT' and d.scheduleddate BETWEEN '08/02/2017' AND '08/03/2017' and d.dropno!=0 and d.location in ('MIAMID') AND (e.etype=107 or e.etype=108) order by d.location, d.dropno, e.etype

Estimated Cost: 304
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 71
Temporary Files Required For: Order By

  1) jlong.d: INDEX PATH

        Filters: (jlong.d.statusmessage = 'CURRENT' AND jlong.d.dropno != 0 )

    (1) Index Name: informix.delivcapac1idx
        Index Keys: scheduleddate location client customername   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Index Self Join Keys (scheduleddate )
          Lower bound: jlong.d.scheduleddate >= 08/02/2017
          Upper bound: jlong.d.scheduleddate <= 08/03/2017

        Lower Index Filter: jlong.d.scheduleddate = jlong.d.scheduleddate AND jlong.d.location = 'MIAMID'

  2) jlong.o: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix. 126_300
        Index Keys: client carrier location code   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: (((jlong.d.driver = jlong.o.code AND jlong.d.location = jlong.o.location ) AND jlong.d.carrier = jlong.o.carrier ) AND jlong.d.client = jlong.o.client )
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  3) jlong.e: INDEX PATH

        Filters: ((((jlong.d.carrier = jlong.e.ecarrier AND (jlong.e.etype = 107 OR jlong.e.etype = 108 ) ) AND jlong.d.location = jlong.e.elocation ) AND jlong.d.client = jlong.e.eclient ) AND jlong.e.elocation = 'MIAMID' )

    (1) Index Name: informix.ix154_17
        Index Keys: eserialno   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: jlong.d.serialno = jlong.e.eserialno
NESTED LOOP JOIN


Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                d
  t2                o
  t3                e

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     603        71        742        00:00.00   122

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t2     603        741       603        00:00.00   1

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   603        71        00:00.00   158

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t3     876        1597      1729       00:00.00   2

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   1044       71        00:00.01   291

  type     rows_sort  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  sort     1044       71        1044       00:00.01   14


QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 09-06-2017 11:27:29)
------
select d.serialno, d.location, d.ticket, d.vehicle, o.name, d.parrivaltime, e.etype from deliveries d left outer join events e on d.serialno=e.eserialno and d.client=e.eclient and d.carrier=e.ecarrier and d.location=e.elocation left outer join operators o on d.client=o.client AND d.driver=o.code AND d.carrier=o.carrier AND d.location=o.location where d.statusmessage='CURRENT' and d.scheduleddate BETWEEN '08/02/2017' AND '08/03/2017' and d.dropno!=0 and d.location in ('MIAMID') AND (e.etype=107 or e.etype=108) order by d.location, d.dropno, e.etype

Estimated Cost: 254
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 1
Temporary Files Required For: Order By

          1) jlong.d: INDEX PATH

                Filters: (jlong.d.statusmessage = 'CURRENT' AND jlong.d.dropno != 0 )

            (1) Index Name: informix.delivcapac1idx
                Index Keys: scheduleddate location client customername   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
                Index Self Join Keys (scheduleddate )
                  Lower bound: jlong.d.scheduleddate >= 08/02/2017
                  Upper bound: jlong.d.scheduleddate <= 08/03/2017

                Lower Index Filter: jlong.d.scheduleddate = jlong.d.scheduleddate AND jlong.d.location = 'MIAMID'

          2) jlong.e: INDEX PATH

                Filters: ((jlong.e.etype = 107 OR jlong.e.etype = 108 ) AND jlong.e.elocation = 'MIAMID' )

            (1) Index Name: informix.ix154_17
                Index Keys: eserialno   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
                Lower Index Filter: jlong.d.serialno = jlong.e.eserialno

        ON-Filters:(((jlong.d.serialno = jlong.e.eserialno AND jlong.d.client = jlong.e.eclient ) AND jlong.d.carrier = jlong.e.ecarrier ) AND jlong.d.location = jlong.e.elocation )
        NESTED LOOP JOIN

      3) jlong.o: INDEX PATH

        (1) Index Name: informix. 126_300
            Index Keys: client carrier location code   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
            Lower Index Filter: (((jlong.d.client = jlong.o.client AND jlong.d.driver = jlong.o.code ) AND jlong.d.carrier = jlong.o.carrier ) AND jlong.d.location = jlong.o.location )

    ON-Filters:(((jlong.d.client = jlong.o.client AND jlong.d.driver = jlong.o.code ) AND jlong.d.carrier = jlong.o.carrier ) AND jlong.d.location = jlong.o.location )
    NESTED LOOP JOIN(LEFT OUTER JOIN)



Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                d
  t2                e
  t3                o

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     603        71        742        00:00.00   122

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t2     1752       1597      1729       00:00.00   2

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   876        1         00:00.00   254

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t3     1752       9862      876        00:00.00   1

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   876        1         00:00.01   254

  type     rows_sort  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  sort     876        1         876        00:00.01   0
```

Can anybody help to analyze the explain file and give the reason of different output?

Thanks

Comment: Look up a definition of left join. It returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Now tell us why you think the answers should be the same. Also what the difference in the outputs are. And what you expected. And what you newly expect. Also, for a simpler example. Indeed please read & act on [mcve]. Not giving one is reason to block answers to your question. Notice one of those words is 'minimal'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/3404097](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/3404097). But be sure to read my answer & comments re the many poor answers and bogus diagrams.